# Stackoverflow Exception while dynamic weaving in Spring-Eclipselink application on WebSphere

Tags: spring-mvc, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, websphere-8, load-time-weaving

I am working on a project which has Spring 4.0, Eclipselink 2.6.3 as JPA with WebSphere 8.5 app server. I am NOT using Maven.

I have given -javaagent:eclipselink-2.6.3.jar (absolute path).

Whenever I restart server, I get following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: operating system stack overflow
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.transformClass(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1987)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:851)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.transformClass(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1987)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:851)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:827)
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.transformClass(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1987)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:851)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEMFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1584)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1406)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPxmlInfo.extractPersistenceUnits(JPAPxmlInfo.java:246)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAScopeInfo.processPersistenceUnit(JPAScopeInfo.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo.processModulePUs(JPAApplInfo.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.AbstractJPAComponent.startingModule(AbstractJPAComponent.java:451)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.startingDeployedModule(JPAComponentImpl.java:771)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.adjust(JPAComponentImpl.java:559)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.adjust(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectAdjust(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1406)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:971)
    ... 13 more
```

After looking in decompiled code of jar, it was found that `PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl` tries to load `EntityManagerFactoryImpl` for which the `ClassLoader` is called. This in turn calls IBMs `CompoundClassLoader`.

Here it calls parents loadClass method which throws ClassNotFoundException. And hence it goes ini catch block and calls localFindClass. This whole process repeats itself and ultimately Stackoverflow Exception is thrown.

The question here is that how the classloader could not find `EntityManagerFactoryImpl` (part of Eclipselink.jar) while loading in  `PersistenceProvider` (which is also part of Eclipselink.jar).

Comment: facing the similar issue while using both dynamic and static weaving with same configurations (IBM websphere 8 , Eclipselink 2.6, Spring)

Comment: How is your application class loader configured (PARENT_FIRST or PARENT_LAST)?  The fact that the class loader is calling defineClass means that it actually found the class it was looking for locally.  If you need the class loaded from the Java agent, it probably can't be in a PARENT_LAST application loader at the same time, or it'll never bother to delegate to the copy in the agent library.

Comment: So just to be clear, this is WebSphere traditional 8.5.x server, not WebSphere Liberty server, correct?  For this answer I am going to assume the former.

1) For the application server environment, you should not be specifying a java agent, the JEE environment will register class transformers for all persistence units in the regular legal locations. (JPA 2.0 spec section 8.2)  As long as the persistence unit defines Eclipselink as the provider via the <provider> tag, entity classes associated with that persistence unit will get transformed using Eclipselink.

Comment: 2) WebSphere Traditional 8.5.x is a JEE 6 environment, which means it is at the JPA 2.0 specification level.  Eclipselink 2.6.x is at the JPA 2.1 specification level.  If you want to use Eclipselink, you will have to go back to its 2.4.x version level, which was the last level which supports JPA at the 2.0 spec level.  If you need JPA 2.1 features, then you will need to update to WebSphere 9.0, or use WebSphere Liberty and its jpa-2.1 feature.  Note that WebSphere 9/Liberty jpa-2.1 feature both ship Eclipselink 2.6 out of the box.

Comment: @FyreWyld mine is IBM webserver 8.5.5.8 not liberty and like Jarid mentioned I have PARENT_FIRST configured.still facing the same issue as the OP mentioned in the question

Comment: @FyreWyld i have tried removing javaagent from JVM arguments. Kept "eclipselink.weaving" as "true". Still facing the same issue of stackoverflow exception because of circular loading. Also, the class loader order is PARENT_FIRST.

Comment: @ Angular_10  you might want to create your own question and show the error you get when you are trying static weaving.  Try a different JVM for compiling.

Comment: @Shrey Bansod Do you have multiple versions of the jars?  How have you added the eclipselink-2.6.3.jar to the classpath?

Comment: Also seems strange that the container would try transforming the JPA provider classes.  Try putting the eclipselink and JPA jars on the container classpath if possible

Comment: @Chris .. I have a single jar of eclipselink-2.6.3.jar.. it is in the lib folder of my EAR and added to the classpath as well... everything works fine if i keep weaving false.. the problem is LAZY loading for OneToOne will not work.. When I make weaving true, i get the issue on startup... what exactly you mean by adding eclipselink jar to container classpath as webspehre itself comes with JPA 2 jars...

Comment: The issue seems to be that Weblogic is trying to run weaving on the eclipselink classes, not your entity classes as it is required to do.  So something is messed up with its classloading.  instead of having the eclipselink jar in your EAR, put it on your container's classpath.  Hopefully the agent only runs on the application classloader and it avoids the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just for history, using the 2.4.2 and put the target in persistence.xml, it worked.

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebSphere_7"/>
```